# Jquery Ui tabs loads to page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, forms, gridview, jquery-ui-tabs

I am using a jquery Ui tabs in my application

In this i am loading three different tabs which has  a asp form on each tab. We know that asp page must have only one  form so i loaded those contents from two other pages like below.

```
<li><a href="#tabs-1">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="user_info.aspx">My Uploads</a></li>
<li><a href="Enquiry.aspx">Enquiry</a></li>
```

In user_info.aspx page i am having a GridView

```
 <form runat="server">
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ></asp:GridView>     
 </form>
```

I have added a pagenation in my grid view which on changing page loads that user_info.aspx page. Is there a way to load this inside the after when i am changing the pagenation pages of grid view.

Comment: I'm not sure this is going to work the way you're hoping. It might be easier to convert user_info.aspx into an ascx user control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: After much researching I came to the conclusion that this cannot be done the way you are trying to do it. The reason why is because when you load the `user_info.aspx` page into `Default.aspx` you are having 2 forms with id `form1` in your page. Therefore, when the `__doPostBack()` function is called by clicking in the GridViews pages, you will get a Javascript exception because the `__doPostBack()` being called is the one from `Default.aspx`. Since you are passing arguments from `user_info.aspx` (`GridView1`), you get the error. If you change one of the ids of the forms in your pages, and click in the GridView's page, you will get an asp.net exception, because the ViewState is going to be invalid (in case you also change the action of the form, to Default.aspx).

Not everything is bad news, you have some solutions:

**Solution 1**: Simply add the `GridView` to your tab.

**Solution 2**: Add an `IFrame` pointing to `user_info.aspx`. If you REALLY have to have the GridView in a different page, I would go with this solution.

**Example**:

**Markup**:

```
<div id="tabs-2">
    <iframe src="user_info.aspx" id="myFrame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

**jQuery**:

```
$('#myFrame').load(function () {
    $(this).height($(this).contents().height());
    $(this).width($(this).contents().width());
});
```

This jQuery makes the `IFrame` fit it's content. It really does look like it belongs there (it's also borderless), and if you change the page, it stays in the same tab.

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: I am using asp.net(C#) here. i have used this method http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax to load dynamic pages here.

Comment: How to give divid of the content to the tab which is in another page?

Comment: Sorry, your scenario is very unclear. You will have to explain it better to me.

Comment: fine. I am having the grid view in another page user_info.aspx but my tabs in default.aspx page. How can i link divId directly to tabs?

Comment: Where to add the script you have given here in default.aspx or user_info.aspx

Comment: Now I understand. I will work in an better example and post it.

Comment: @Jhonny I have updated the answer. It's all I could do, check it out.